# Excel Macro: Command buttons overlap the shape in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 command buttons, different height and width of the cells that need to be inserted every time and a fixed shape. Sometimes when the height and width are smaller, it tend to overlap with the command buttons. What should I do? I need the command buttons to be there. I tried to put certain range, it works but when the width and height of the cells gets bigger, it moves further away. Any idea? I'm thinking of maybe putting the range cells for the command buttons to stay as Range A and B as default. Will that work? But I don't know how to do it.

[image: Here's the example:]

Answer (score 0):

Set the top, left properties on the shape, then irrespective of the size it should always start at the same place.

```
Dim Fred as shape
Set Fred = activesheet.shapes.addshape(type,left,top etc,)
Fred.placement= xlfreefloating
```

Comment: I made the shape starts at certain range, but when the row and column gets smaller, it will overlap with the command buttons. So, I was thinking, is there a way to lock the range where I put my command buttons? So it won't overlap with the shape when I change the row and column, but when the row and column is bigger, the shape will move further back.